# NodeJS/Angular - Adding input from form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, forms, mongodb

I'm working on adding a new entry using NodeJS with an Angular form. However, when I click create it doesn't input the data to the database. I added the angular.toJson to convert the input into a json for input to Mongodb, but it doesn't work. How would I fix this code to add the form entry data to the database?

Angular Add Controller

```
.controller('AddNew', function($scope, $http) { 
$scope.addnew = "Add New item"; 

$scope.item = {}; 

$scope.create = function() {  

   item = $scope.item; 

   var input = angular.toJson(item);  

   $http.post("http://localhost:3000/api/book", input); 

} 

})
```

NodeJS Code

```
  //Add a new book
app.post("/api/book", function(req, res){ 

 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma,    
  Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
  console.log("Adding new Book: " + req.body.name);
  var book = new Book({
   name:req.body.name,
   isbn: req.body.isbn,
   author: req.body.author,
pages: req.body.pages
 });

//Saving the model instance to the DB
 book.save(function(err, result){
   if ( err ) throw err;
   res.json({
   message:"Successfully added book",
    book:result
   });
 });
 });
```

Comment: Just noticed a typo: `messaage`

Comment: if you are getting req.body then it should work otherwise use node module for bodyparser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your request code line like below:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/book",
    data: $.param(item),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
```

And include this lines to your server-side:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': 'true'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

You need jquery for use `$.param`, if you not include jQuery to your project, you can bind params like this:

```
'name='+item.name+'&isbn='+item.isbn
```

And be sure define `body-parser` in your express application.

Comment: Just did this without jQuery. There is an input, but it only shows the __id and a "__v" : 0.

Comment: are you sure define body-parser in server-side? please share me output of console.log(req.body)

Comment: I get a req is not defined. On my server side, I have included var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); and using app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: you must write `console.log(req.body)` line after `app.post("/api/book", function(req, res){`  line, but if you already include bodyParser its should be work. Look my updated answer.

Comment: Basaran, with your edit I got it to work. Thank yo so much!